# Can I use only the parser of flyway

Tags: flyway

I'd like to use only the parser of flyway to parse SQL scripts and execute them over JDBC. Currently I made a simple parser myself that does the job. But only for the cases I met so far. I'd like to use the flyway parser as I think it is more sophisticated. Is there a way to use some of the flyway classes to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not explicitly supported. But if you're willing to accept the risk of things breaking between releases (as this isn't part of the published api), have a look at the com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport package and the SqlScript class. You can see how to instantiate it independently by looking at the metadata table format migration code in the com.googlecode.flyway.core.metadatatable package.